# regex java replace all

Tags: java, regex

```
String url = "/users/{id}/books/{id_book}";

url = url.replaceAll("{\\w*}", "\\w*");

System.out.println("result url:" + url);
```

Tentando fazer um replace com regex, e me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{\w*}
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3157)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2134)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
    at br.com.rileyframework.TestRegex.main(TestRegex.java:10)
```

Resultado que espero:

```
/users/\w*/books/\w*
```

Comment: Você que substituir {id} e {id_book} por {\\w*} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa fazer o *escape* das chaves.

```
String url = "/users/{id}/books/{id_book}";
url = url.replaceAll("\\{\\w*\\}", "\\\\w*");
System.out.println("result url:" + url);
```

Comment: valeu! funcionou :)